# Mostrar o esconder la consola en una aplicación de consola

Tags: c#, visual-studio, consola

Me preguntaba como se puede mostrar o esconder la consola al lanzar una aplicación de consola (.NET Framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta con que vayas a las propiedades del proyecto y cambies el tipo de la salida de Aplicación de consola (aquí se mostrará la consola) a Aplicación de Windows (con esta configuración no se mostrará la consola)

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

La solución publicada por el compañero es optima para esconder la consola, existe otra manera que funciona para ocultar y mostrar la consola, se ealiza mediente un puntero que se maneja por la Estructura Intpr, a continuacion el codigo:

```
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

   Class Program
   {
       [DllImport("user32.dll")]
       public static extern IntPtr EncontraVentana(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

       [DllImport("user32.dll")]
       static extern bool MostrarVentana(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           Console.Title = "MyConsoleApp";

           ManejoConsola(false, Console.Title);

       }

       public static void ManejoConsola(bool visible, string titulo)
       {
           IntPtr resultado = EncontraVentana(null, titulo); //Nombre de la consola

           if (resultado != IntPtr.Zero)
           {
               if(!visible)
               {
                   //Esconder Ventana
                   MostrarVentana(resultado, 0); // 0 = Esconder
               }
               else
               {
                   //Mostrar Vnetana
                   MostrarVentana(resultado, 1); //1 = Mostrar
               }
           }
       }

    }
```